# Backbone.js and Require.js: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (_, Backbone) {

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I am new to using require.js and have the following app.js file as part of my backbone app:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "/js/",
paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery-2.1.0',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone-min'
},
shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports: "_"
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
}
});
```

In a  tag in my index.html file, I have placed the following:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone'], function (_, Backbone) {
```

However, I am getting the following error my index.html file:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
```

And the following in my require.js file:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (_, Backbone) {
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the config above,

[image: as you can see is there minimals diffs]

As you can see comparing my sample image with you way to declare, is there minimals diffs:

- **You don't need to declare `shim` libs at `paths`, just use the same name**;
- My baseUrl starts on my `js\lib` folder;
- I'm using file name on my json config;

When I declare the "setup" on my main html page I'm using like that:

```
<script data-main="js/setup.js" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: In looking at my config. Do you know what is causing the error?

Comment: I believe if you try to declare as I did, you can fix your problem, but I could guess on the way are you declaring the libs, as you can see on my sample I don't make reference in "paths" on my js libs, I just rename then and make the baseUrl starts on my lib folder.

Comment: Thanks Claudio. Does this line add your router? "require({"config/urlRoutes", "backbone", "bootstrap"] That's where it appears to be tripping up for me at the moment

Comment: yes, this is just for the backbone route, are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Not anymore. I added the call to the route and defined the JavaScript files I needed in the define.