# Convert existing web project to requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have an existing project that structure something like this, just like normal common webpage:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/nanoscroller.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/myscript1.js"></script>
<script src="js/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
     // my inline script
     // some code which should run after myscript1.js
});
</script>
<script src="myscript2.js"></script>
```

Now, I try to do it with requirejs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var require = {
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        'jquery'       : ['jquery.min'],
        'bootstrap'    : ['bootstrap.min'],
        'nanoscroller' : ['nanoscroller.min'],
        'bootbox'      : ['bootbox.min'],
        'myscript1'    : ['myscript1'],
        'tinymce'      : ['tinymce.min']
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap'    : ['jquery'],
        'nanoscroller' : ['jquery'],
        'bootbox'      : ['bootstrap']
    }
}
</script>
<script src="require.js"></script>
<script>
require(['myscript1','tinymce'],function(){
    $(function(){
        // my inline script
        // some code which should run after myscript1.js
    });
}
</script>
<script src="myscript2.js"></script>
```

In myscript1.js

```
define(['jquery','bootstrap','nanoscroller','bootbox'],function(){
      //all the myscript1 original code here
}
```

In myscript2.js

```
require(['myscript1','tinymce'],function(){
      //all the myscript2 original code here
}
```

Well, this is just example to illustrate the structure. In my real project there are a lot more plugins and myscript.

The problem is when I run the page, sometimes everything is running and most of the time some of my script code doesn't even execute. Especially inline script. The biggest trouble is, many of the time I can't see any error in my console window. No sign of error showing up at all. No way to trace. I also try with `requirejs.onError`, but it doesn't seem help at all.

When it does shows up error, usually is jquery is not loaded problem. I am very curious as I have added jquery as the requirement for all of it. But, how can if the jquery is not loaded and it goes to execute the code?

Is it because my structure is wrong? Do I really need to rewrite the whole project just to get it works with requirejs? If you know how, please guide me with example of code for easier understanding.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds that you have been the same problem from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143506/backbone-js-and-require-js-mismatched-anonymous-define-module-function-b/23146441#23146441), please take a look.

Comment: You'd benefit from actually reading the RequireJS documentation; parameters of `paths` and `shim` are not arrays but, respectively, strings and `deps`/`exports` object. One of the symptoms of misconfiguration is what you're seeing: sometimes works (due to lucky timing and loading order), sometimes doesn't.